# android add a button at the end of webview (overlapping webpage)

Tags: android, html, button, webview

I have a webview with a website URL,
the website is about 1000px(it can change)
I would like a button to showup at the end of the URL (on footer overlapping)

If the above is not possible then a button should always appear at the bottom of webview just above our home and back button.

Below is what I tried.

Thanks in advance for your help and support.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="XXX" />

</WebView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly, you mention that you want to replace the footer of the website with your own button right? You can do like this.. it will place as static button overlaying webview layout. You need to make sure your footer height is the same as Button that you need to overlay.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="XXX" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use below method to resize your button height to be same as your website footer

ex:

```
buttonUrl.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, pxToDP(1000)));


public static int pxToDp(int px) {
    return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot **ZeroOne**

Comment: @ZeroOne but will this button scroll/move along with the webview ?? I think i will remain static.

Comment: I want the buttons to be at the bottom and also scroll with the webview just as the website. How to do that ?

Comment: @B.shruti.. it will remain the bottom because of `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in RL.. try put it inside scrollview and fixed the height of the webview.. it would be tricky part when you need to handle onTouch method

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnOk"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  to use Linear Layout with Vertical orientation instead of Relative Layout..

Answer (score 0):

**RelativeLayout** is a view group that displays child views in relative positions. You tried to add button inside weview which is wrong implementation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="XXX" />
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```